# Ошибка Incorrect string value с MySQL и PHP кириллица

Tags: php, mysql

Не совсем понимаю, с чем может быть связана следующая проблема:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xD0\xBF\xD0\xB5\xD1\x80...' for column 'title' at row 1
```

А вот тот PHP код, который это вызывает:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pass');
        if($link&&isset($_POST['addSticker'])){
            $title = $_POST['title'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $photo = mysql_real_escape_string(urlencode($_POST['photo']));
            $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];
            mysql_select_db('dbName');
            $sql = "INSERT INTO table (title, description, photo, quantity, price) VALUES ('$title', '$description', '$photo', '$quantity', '$price');";
            mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $link);
            mysql_query($sql, $link) or die(mysql_error());
        }
```

Суть на мой взгляд в том, что при добавлении товара, используются символы кириллицы и есть ссылка (https). Мне кажется, что именно один из этих моментов вызывает ошибку.

Comment: В какой кодировке ваш скрипт и какая кодировка была указана для таблицы table?

Comment: спасибо, разобрался ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Имхо `urlencode($_POST['photo'])` гадит. Он преобразует все, что не валидный символ для `URL` в `UNICODE`.